# External link in a src attribute not working in emulator

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want to display an image where its source is an external link. This is working in a browser but not working in Emulator

```
<div id="EmpDisplayPic" style="float: left;">
    <img id="empPic" alt="" src="http://183.82.99.100:9080/emp/GetPhoto?empId=7"  width="90px" height="100px" style="border-radius: 12px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested a simple img tag in an Android device and the image displayed just fine.

```
<img src="http://183.82.99.100:9080/emp/GetPhoto?empId=7">
```

It could be that your Emulator is not connected to the Internet.
The code itself is fine.